# Is it possible to reorganize coloring/highlighting priority in Texmaker?

Tags: math-mode, color, highlighting, texmaker

I want to be able to see latex commands in Texmaker while in mathmode, but the settings file does not seem to account for priority via line rearrangement, so I was wondering if there was a way to make the text coloring/highlighting follow a more Winedt-like coloring scheme, that is have the latex command color override the math mode color as opposed to the other way around.  Having the entirety of mathmode as greentext results in less readability rather than more.

Comment: May be this is what you are looking for, Open TeXmaker-->Options-->Configure-->Editor-->Colors-->Math-->`#008000`

Comment: The problem is that it overrides  the latex command coloring, and so regardless of whether there are commands within mathmode, it is all green, making math mode coloring more good than harm.

Comment: may be post a feature request to the [TeXmaker issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/list)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a feature request for an editor. 